# My SUM query returns 2 rows, need some advise

Tags: mysql, sql, sum

I am getting 2 rows(9500) for 111 in the result, could you please advise on the right approach, I need like, Balance = (sum of bought - sum of sold)

```
#Table T1#  
+---------+--------+------+------+  
| ACCOUNT | TRANS  | AMT  | YEAR |  
+---------+--------+------+------+  
|     111 | BOUGHT | 8000 | 2019 |  
|     111 | BOUGHT | 2000 | 2019 | 
|     111 | SOLD   |  500 | 2019 |  
|     222 | BOUGHT | 6000 | 2018 |  
|     222 | SOLD   |  300 | 2018 |  
+---------+--------+------+------+
```

Query

```
SELECT (A.BOUGHTs - B.SOLDs) AS BALANCE  
  FROM T1 
 INNER JOIN  
  (SELECT SUM(AMT) AS BOUGHTs  
     FROM T1  
    WHERE TRANS = 'BOUGHT'  
  ) A  
   ON T1.ACCOUNT = A.ACCOUNT  
 INNER JOIN  
  (SELECT SUM(AMT) AS SOLDs  
     FROM T2  
    WHERE TRANS = 'SOLD'  
  ) B  
   ON T1.ACCOUNT = B.ACCOUNT  
WHERE T1.ACCOUNT = 111  
  AND T1.YEAR    = 2019
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select account, year,
       sum(case when trans = 'bought' then amt 
                when trans = 'sold' then - amt
                else 0
           end) as diff
from t
group by account, year;
```

If you want this for only one account, you can add a `where` clause:

```
select account, year,
       sum(case when trans = 'bought' then amt 
                when trans = 'sold' then - amt
                else 0
           end) as diff
from t
where account = 111 and year = 2019
group by account, year;
```

Comment: Worked Thank You Sir!!

Comment: @Rajs . . . I'm surprised you didn't accept this answer which is not only simpler but also appeared 15 minutes earlier.

Comment: I am new here, got it now. Accepted Sir!

Answer (score 0):

Rewriting your query will look like this:

```
SELECT (A.BOUGHTs - B.SOLDs) AS BALANCE
  FROM
    (SELECT ACCOUNT,YEAR,SUM(AMT) AS BOUGHTs FROM T1 WHERE TRANS = 'BOUGHT' GROUP BY ACCOUNT,YEAR) A
    INNER JOIN
    (SELECT ACCOUNT,YEAR,SUM(AMT) AS SOLDs FROM T1 WHERE TRANS = 'SOLD' GROUP BY ACCOUNT,YEAR) B
    ON A.ACCOUNT=B.ACCOUNT AND A.YEAR=B.YEAR
WHERE A.ACCOUNT = 111
  AND A.YEAR    = 2019;
```

Comment: Understood the mistake in my query. Thanks!